# How should I create the time series when the path settings is dynamically spliced in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Do I need to create an empty time series first before writing data into Apache IoTDB? Since the path of time series is dynamically spliced, is there any good method for me to create time series? Also, is the attribute in IoTDB cannot be used as a query condition, and the label can be used as a query condition?

Previously, I did not understand the relationship between metadata creation and time series data insertion in Apache IoTDB. Also, since for my scenario, the path settings are dynamically spliced, I want to know if the automatic creation of metadata in IoTDB can still be used in this case. I checked the asked questions in apache-iotdb tag and no question was asked for this specific situation, so I post this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is an `enable_auto_create_schema` parameter in `conf/iotdb-common.properties` directory of Apache IoTDB. Its default value is true, which means that metadata is allowed to be automatically created when using the `insert` statement, and it will automatically identify the datatype of metadata. However, this automatic recognition of datatype may not be the type you expected, so it is best to create the metadata first and then insert the data.
2. Attributes are only for display use in Apache IoTDB and do not participate in queries. If you need to have a similar property that can be used as a query condition, tag in IoTDB can be used.